# NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust challenge called every time

Tags: ios, https

**Situation**: I am building an enterprise App which can be used for sharing Pictures etc. It was using HTTP and now I moved to HTTPS as it is going public. I have the client certificates (.cer) bundled in the App.

I have followed through most of the discussions here and the post by Eskimo on AppDev forum (https://devforums.apple.com/message/737087#737087) and here (http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-https-certificate-handling-to-protect-your-ios-app/). But my problem is that my App has multiple calls to the same HTTPS server and for each time I keep getting the NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust challenge. Is this normal? 'coz for each challenge I lose close to 4 seconds of transaction time and my pictures take time to load.

Also, please see the NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault challenge IF condition comment, really not sure why that is going this way.

So to sum up.
1. Do I have to check certificates and verify for every HTTPS call?
2. Why is the Authentication challenge (NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault) not working if I put inside the IF block.

Any help here would be appreciated.

```
-(BOOL) shouldTrustProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *) protectionSpace{

    NSString *certPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file.something.com" ofType:@"cer"];
    NSData   *certData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:certPath];
    CFDataRef certDataRef = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)certData;
    SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL,certDataRef);

    CFArrayRef certArrayRef = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (void *)&cert,1,NULL);
    SecTrustRef serverTrust =  protectionSpace.serverTrust;
    SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(serverTrust, certArrayRef);


    SecTrustResultType trustResult;
    SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &trustResult);

    if ( trustResult == kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure){

        NSLog(@"kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure");
        CFDataRef errDataRef = SecTrustCopyExceptions(serverTrust);
        SecTrustSetExceptions(serverTrust, errDataRef);

        SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &trustResult);

    }

    if ( trustResult == kSecTrustResultUnspecified){
        NSLog(@"In Trust: kSecTrustResultUnspecified");
    }

    if ( trustResult == kSecTrustResultProceed){
        NSLog(@"In Trust: kSecTrustResultProceed");
    }


    return trustResult == kSecTrustResultUnspecified || trustResult == kSecTrustResultProceed;

}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler{

    NSLog(@"didReceiveChallenge");




    if ([self shouldTrustProtectionSpace:[challenge protectionSpace]]) {


        SecTrustRef trust = [[challenge protectionSpace] serverTrust];
        SecCertificateRef certificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trust, 0);

        NSData *serverCertificateData = (__bridge NSData *)SecCertificateCopyData(certificate);


        NSURL *bundledCertURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"file.something.com" withExtension:@"cer"];
        NSData *bundledCertData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:bundledCertURL];

        BOOL whatWeExpected = [serverCertificateData isEqual:bundledCertData];


        if (whatWeExpected == TRUE ){

            NSLog(@"As Expected");

            NSURLCredential *cred = [[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithTrust:trust];
            [[challenge sender] useCredential:cred forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

        }

    }

    if ([[[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod] isEqualToString: NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault]) {

        NSLog(@"NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault");

    }



    //This piece of code I put it outside the above IF for now else I never get
    //the NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault challenge?????

    NSURLCredential *newCredential;
    newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:userName
                                               password:passWord
                                            persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, newCredential);


}
```